# Android: Target SDK = 21 (Lollipop), but not Fully Themed on Older Devices

Tags: android, dialog, themes

I have an android app with a target sdk of 21. For some reason, (specifically) AlertDialogs on non lollipop devices show with that devices sdk level.

EG: On a Lollipop device, the alert will show how i want it.
On my KitKat device, the AlertDialog shows with the KitKat theme.

Is there a way to **force** show dialogs with the min sdk? Or is there a way i can fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of version 22.1.0, AppCompat provides the ability to show Material-themed dialogs on older devices.

If you have a class that extends `Dialog`, change it to extend [`AppCompatDialog`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDialog.html).

If you create dialogs with `AlertDialog.Builder`, switch to [`android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html).

See the [Android Support Library 22.1](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html) blog post for more information.

Comment: Strange, it cannot resolve the symbol! (I am using Android Studio)

Comment: Do you have AppCompat 22.1.0 in your Gradle dependencies?

Comment: No, won't let me do compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0'

but i already have compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'

Comment: Why won't it let you? Have you updated the support repository in your SDK manager recently?

Comment: I forgot to do that! Thanks :)